# Why the initial mse increases with batch size in keras training

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I was training a fully connected neural network with keras, the initial mse loss increases apparently with batch size, while after several epochs, the loss converges to the same value, 0.5 in my case.

The first and second pictures correspond to batch size 20, and the third and fourth pictures correspond to batch size 256. As can be seen from the pictures, the initial loss for the larger batch size is also more than 10 times larger, which is quiet confusing to me since with the same default initialization strategy, the initial losses should be close with different batch sizes.

Hope anyone can help to explain this to me, thank you.

[image: Initial loss for batch size 20]

[image: Convergence loss for batch size 20]

[image: Initial loss for batch size 256]

[image: Convergence loss for batch size 256]

Comment: What type of loss have you used while compiling the model. Is it cross-entropy?

Comment: @ Rahul Vishwakarma It's a regression problem, and the loss is mean squared error. Actually, I am using neural network to denoise, where the input is just label plus gaussian noise.

Comment: What's the range of values of Y (output)?

Comment: @ Rahul Vishwakarma The activation function for the output layer is "linear", i.e., no activation. So the value range of Y could be negative infinity to positive infinity.